# mySQL How to select distinct(1 column : pruduct_Type) from 1st table and select 2 columns from 2nd table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables, i would to select 2 columns from 2nd table for the different product Type distinctly selected from 1st Table.

table 1 :
idTable1 product_Type product_name
1             AD                          Product N1
2             AD                           Product N2
3                    AF                            Product N3
4                    AF                           Product N4

table 2 :
idTable2 typeISO      Manufacturer Phone
21                AD                   Adidas                121212121
22                 AF                  Lacoste               989898989
23                AX                  Nike                      333333333

I would return :

Array :
product_Type Manufacturer Phone
AD                     Adidas                 121212121
AF                             Lacoste              989898989

i tested this query but returns only one column : product_Type :

SELECT DISTINCT 1stTable.product_Type
FROM 1stTable
LEFT JOIN 2ndTable
ON 1stTable.product_Type = 2ndTable.typeISO

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for `exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.product_type = t2.typeISO)
```

This gives you all records in `table2` whose `typeISO` can be found in column `product_type` of `table1`.

Comment: that's OK, Thanks, you saved me a lot.